# ASP.NET MVC Forum?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, forum

I am repeating this question since i haven't found a good answer to it yet. The other threads about this topic is from 2008 and 2009. There are a few projects out there like OpenForum, NearForums and Telerik Forums. The openforum and nearforums i can't even get to run on my computer, just getting a lot of build errors. On the openforum it seems a bit dead on that end in the discussions thread. Telerik requires some components that i can't even find.

So i ask again, maybe there is some new projects in the loop, is there a forum like YAF for asp.net?
It must be MVC 2 or 3 and preferably also have some APIs like YAF so that it can easily be integrated into the webpage.

Comment: Just to be clear, why are you seeking an alternative to YAF? It *is* an open-source ASP.NET forum... isn't it?

Comment: Yea but its not for MVC.

Comment: Can I help you run nearforums? I'm one of the developers of nearforums...

Comment: I actually just wrote a blog post about this, and listed 17 different ones along with a short description of each. Take a look at it here: http://digioz.blogspot.com/2012/10/aspnet-mvc-forum-software.html Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried http://mesoboard.com/ ?

Answer (score 6):

Also try our latest release

http://www.mvcforum.com

The full source/docs is on Github and you can [download via nuget too](https://github.com/leen3o/mvcforum/wiki/Installing)

https://github.com/leen3o/mvcforum

Also, we have a support forum which is actually running the latest version of the forum.

http://support.mvcforum.com

Comment: mvcforum is not free. It is under the GPLv2

Comment: Isn't free as long as you not remove the link at the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

http://mvcforum.codeplex.com not quite ready for release yet, but we're getting there!